# Privacy related to bank account

Tags: banking

If a person wins a massive lottery prize, in the order of 200 million € or £ or $, and this prize is versed to the person's bank account, how can they avoid that their bank balance is gossipped upon by bank employees to the extent of it known by people outside the bank, in case the person DOES want to keep their own privacy? How can they possibly avoid that, assuming that bank employees will definitely not respect privacy laws?

Comment: `assuming that bank employees will definitely not respect privacy laws?` - This is a big assumption.  You also seem to think privacy is some sort of binary; you have it or you don't, but privacy is a spectrum of sorts (ie, if I'm walking around in public lots of people see my face, and may capture me in a photo, but probably don't know my name).  Any large transfers are going to get flagged for review, if for no other reason than to sell some sort of concierge service - and to report to the government for tax reasons.  What are you concerned about here?

Comment: Swiss numbered bank account - although this is an asset management reply to a security question :D.

Comment: Related article: https://www.cnbc.com/2019/06/08/mega-millions-jackpot-won-how-lottery-winners-can-protect-privacy.html   In some states (such as California) the winner has to be identified by name.  So your privacy is already gone.  In other states it is legal for a “trust” to win.  When you win, it is recommended you sign it immediately. But if you personally sign it as winner then a trust cannot win.  But if you wait to setup a trust with a lawyer the ticket is unsigned and is like carrying that amount of cash.  Suggest asking in “legal” forum.  I am not a lawyer.

Comment: Many lottery payouts allow you to spread out the full prize over multiple years, so you would never have the entire balance in your account at once. Or, spread the money among multiple banks and investment accounts.

Comment: Don't deposit it in a single bank account? That seems strange anyway.

Comment: This is more of a banking question than a security question.

Answer (score 3):

**Most Bank employees can't see that info**

In most banks there is a team that is in charge of tracking deposits that reach a threshold, in the case that you define, they need to verify that the money that you deposit in your account is legal.

Depending in the laws in your country the bank will demand for evidence in the regard of from where it came? why do you have it? and what are you going to do with it?

**Bank employees don't care**

This team see this kind of amounts and even higher all day, every day, and some with really really obvious crimmminal background, they also get lottery winners every month, investors/shells that bring everything to shelter from their home country taxes, etc.

Other point is that the clients info is top secret for most banks employees, and nobody can reach that info without a justification, this means that the few that are granted access to this info are heavly monitored.

Comment: Top secret???  Hardly.  By policy they aren't allowed to just snoop around, but the customer service rep sees all my transactions when I call on the phone and discuss a problem with her.

Comment: @RonJohn - *when I call* is a key component in your sentence. In modern banking software, every employee view of personal customer details (PII, transactions, balances) is automatically logged. Just *querying someone's name* is logged. If an employee had looked at your account for no reason except curiosity (i.e. there wasn't a matching call logged in their phone system showing that you asked for help), their activity would be flagged and/or it would be uncovered in an audit. In the US at least, this type of monitoring is essentially enforced via regulators and external audits.

Comment: @dwizum good to know.  That doesn't make it "top secret", though.

Comment: Yes - "top secret" is a little arbitrary. I wanted to comment because I don't think many people understand how tightly monitored the systems in a typical bank are, in terms of employees looking at your personal details.

Comment: @RonJohn sorry, english isn't my first language maybe the right wording would be "highly confidential", as dwizum commented client information inside a bank its a critical asset and an employee snooping around would mean a full scale investigation with law enforcers support if the evidence demand it.

Answer (score 1):

"how can they avoid that their bank balance is gossiped upon by bank employees" -- obviously, **he can't**. He has no control over what the bank employees may do. But the prize is likely transferred electronically, so no employee would have reason to check the account (such operations are logged and "curiosity" is, understandably, strongly discouraged).

This person might open a secondary account online, request the prize to be transferred to *that* account, and periodically transfer funds from the prize account to his ordinary account - if the prize account is in a different bank, even if an employee working with the ordinary account got curious, he could not pry into the fund sources' account information as he would have no access. The prize account bank employees would never see the holder and never have reason to check an account they would be unaware of (one doesn't simply run `SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 20` on a bank's servers. The worst that can **usually** happen is that an employee may access a customer account he knows the number of from the teller station, pretending that the customer is at the desk).

Comment: Any amount of sufficient size to be interesting is going to be flagged for human review, almost certainly (if for no other reason than to check for mistakes), especially for electronic transfers.  Using some "new" bank is not helpful, since presumably the other bank would have the same issue.  Regular transfers of money in useful quantities is going to get your account flagged_more_, because of anti-money-laundering laws, and laws against "structuring".

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: AFAIK structuring is only an issue for US, and there it is only for currency i.e. actual physical cash; you can do electronic transfers or even paper (personal) checks $9999/day all you want. Large and/or frequent transfers _might_ draw a SAR, but I doubt it. Although over $250k/bank doesn't get FDIC insurance.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: It's not just about detection of money laundering (which involves SARs), the bank will assuredly put human eyes on large transfers to protect themselves against human errors and possible fraud.